# Django - Get Id of the ForeignKey Object in List View

Tags: django

I have two models linked by Foreign Key. RunConfig   RunConfig**Status**

```
class RunConfig(models.Model):
    config_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class RunConfigStatus(models.Model):
    config_run_name     = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True )
    config_name         = models.ForeignKey('RunConfig',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)        
    Overall_Status      = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
```

I am currently using a CBV list view for RunConfigStatus. I would like to href/link the foreign key object to its detail view. is this possible?

```
class RunConfigStatusListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = RunConfigStatus
    context_object_name = 'run_config_status_list'
```

On my Template:

```
{% for run in run_config_status_list %}

 <td><a href={% url 'runconfigstatus-detail' pk=run.id %}>{{run.config_run_name}}</a></td>

  <td>{{run.config_name}}</td>                          
  <td>{{run.Overall_Status}}</td>
```

I want that config_name should have a href which will redirect to RunConfig detail view

```
 <td><a href={% url 'runconfig-detail' pk=**NOT SURE** %}>{{run.config_name}}</a></td>
```

Screen Shot of my current output, [image]

I would like to click on Config Name values and it should redirect to its detail view. (In this case Test, MyFirstTest on all entries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible. You're already accessing the runconfig name, you can do exactly the same thing with the pk:

```
<a href="{% url 'runconfig-detail' pk=run.config_name.id %}">
```

However you should really pick a less confusing name for the foreign key; the field `config_name` doesn't point to a name, it points to a RunConfig instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel,  This worked for me.

You are right I should use different name,This name actually made me forget that config_name is a instance.